# Bind9 - "label too long"

Tags: dns, debian, bind, subdomain, nameservers

Is there any way to increase the lentght of a subdomain (A record) in pri.example.com file so the Bind9 can load a long subdomains without displaying "label too long" e.g.:

```
this-is-a-subdomain-number-one   $ATTL IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
this-is-a-subdomain-number-two   $ATTL IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
this-is-a-subdomain-number-three-that-one-of-my-clients-wish-to-use-for-his-website-but-bind9-upon-loading-is-displaying-label-to-long-error   $ATTL IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
this-is-a-subdomain-number-four   $ATTL IN A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

**this-is-a-subdomain-number-one.example.com**, **this-is-a-subdomain-number-two.example.com** and **this-is-a-subdomain-number-four.com** work fine, but bind9 can't load **this-is-a-subdomain-number-three-that-one-of-my-clients-wish-to-use-for-his-website-but-bind9-upon-loading-is-displaying-label-to-long-error.example.com** :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the 'pedia

`Each label may contain up to 63 characters. The full domain name may not exceed the length of 253 characters in its textual representation. In the internal binary representation of the DNS the maximum length requires 255 octets of storage, since it also stores the length of the name.`